# Parsing nested JSON arrays in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm having a hard time working out how to parse JSON in Swift.
I want to parse out the RouteKey and routeNAME from this xml.
I've tried a few different tutorials, and tried to work out quicktype but I couldn't get it to work.

```
{
"response": {
    "data": [{
        "fieldData": {
            "RouteKey": "AIwACAAAAB4AAABcAAAAmQAAAKYAAAB42mNYxsDOZMfAwMCyjIFhHSMDwy8g24SDgYGJCchg6I39 MjFlkOdAQr2VBQICTFU2jD8\/w8R LCfAQlwAXHqlS5OJoaXd249WvXjtxpMZtuOfCFmhkorPBq5996vADqACS6odOH0dpDNigIMHgwA UQgxkMEKTE=",
            "Route ID": 3.5375656527008e+56,
            "userID": "1",
            "routeNAME": "Zoo to Hartley",
            "Job ID": "",
            "RouteXML": "",
            "length": "",
            "width": "",
            "weight": "",
            "height": "",
            "numtrailers": "",
            "truckID": "1"
        },
        "portalData": [],
        "recordId": "14",
        "modId": "1"
    }, {
        "fieldData": {
            "RouteKey": "ADYBCAAAAB4AAABcAAAAmQAAAJsBAAB42n1QPUtDMRQ9SSMNtmj6dCi6BIVHnbS4KkR4Q10F97e5Kbi5RXmV2lUXcSn0P2g3K3QouIjg1kUnR0EnEetNXipOHrhJ7uc5ubhiRQ6CP 6f7eNsZFYQ0Pk4jw750QbG4zzwdos\/mCa7rC99c2y j16eFr7iSeamdxBp\/Nv4IEbrLPB6DPY r3cksLpM0XR xsUE czXhDqpwU1X9fcBTa7iYClaIiTJrHtUXeCMWxjX2FeIOVHRJLPdtAyiAYXkDqhAppiTUxwl4WdU5W6BJqyJVh2d41OzGNcudLuGyskWQ2aSpPRaJI62wJB oQXx2wxoOHmmQHqIXzvRQNlv1bD8hnAfUE4DgspuLniyfFv 3YQln9lmhh NMTn3hVV0jw==",
            "Route ID": 2.7005919429558e+57,
            "userID": "1",
            "routeNAME": "Perth to Hartley",
            "Job ID": "",
            "RouteXML": "",
            "length": "",
            "width": "",
            "weight": "",
            "height": "",
            "numtrailers": "",
            "truckID": "1"
        },
        "portalData": [],
        "recordId": "19",
        "modId": "1"
    }]
},
"messages": [{
    "code": "0",
    "message": "OK"
}]
```

}

This is the code I have so far that retrieves the JSON:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://....")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? NSDictionary {
print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "response")!)
}
}).resume()
```

Comment: One word: [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wan't to make it work with `Codable` [HERE](https://app.quicktype.io?share=l0KzbhyyDujEeaS98TPx) is your file.

And it will look like:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let response: Response
    let messages: [Message]
}

struct Message: Codable {
    let code, message: String
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let data: [Datum]
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let fieldData: FieldData
    let portalData: [JSONAny]
    let recordID, modID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fieldData, portalData
        case recordID = "recordId"
        case modID = "modId"
    }
}

struct FieldData: Codable {
    let routeKey: String
    let routeID: Double
    let userID, routeNAME, jobID, routeXML: String
    let length, width, weight, height: String
    let numtrailers, truckID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case routeKey = "RouteKey"
        case routeID = "Route ID"
        case userID, routeNAME
        case jobID = "Job ID"
        case routeXML = "RouteXML"
        case length, width, weight, height, numtrailers, truckID
    }
}

// MARK: Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}

class JSONCodingKey: CodingKey {
    let key: String

    required init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }

    required init?(stringValue: String) {
        key = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int? {
        return nil
    }

    var stringValue: String {
        return key
    }
}

class JSONAny: Codable {
    let value: Any

    static func decodingError(forCodingPath codingPath: [CodingKey]) -> DecodingError {
        let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Cannot decode JSONAny")
        return DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONAny.self, context)
    }

    static func encodingError(forValue value: Any, codingPath: [CodingKey]) -> EncodingError {
        let context = EncodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath, debugDescription: "Cannot encode JSONAny")
        return EncodingError.invalidValue(value, context)
    }

    static func decode(from container: SingleValueDecodingContainer) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            return value
        }
        if container.decodeNil() {
            return JSONNull()
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decode(from container: inout UnkeyedDecodingContainer) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decodeNil() {
            if value {
                return JSONNull()
            }
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedUnkeyedContainer() {
            return try decodeArray(from: &container)
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self) {
            return try decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decode(from container: inout KeyedDecodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>, forKey key: JSONCodingKey) throws -> Any {
        if let value = try? container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int64.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(Double.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: key) {
            return value
        }
        if let value = try? container.decodeNil(forKey: key) {
            if value {
                return JSONNull()
            }
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key) {
            return try decodeArray(from: &container)
        }
        if var container = try? container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self, forKey: key) {
            return try decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        }
        throw decodingError(forCodingPath: container.codingPath)
    }

    static func decodeArray(from container: inout UnkeyedDecodingContainer) throws -> [Any] {
        var arr: [Any] = []
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let value = try decode(from: &container)
            arr.append(value)
        }
        return arr
    }

    static func decodeDictionary(from container: inout KeyedDecodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>) throws -> [String: Any] {
        var dict = [String: Any]()
        for key in container.allKeys {
            let value = try decode(from: &container, forKey: key)
            dict[key.stringValue] = value
        }
        return dict
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout UnkeyedEncodingContainer, array: [Any]) throws {
        for value in array {
            if let value = value as? Bool {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? Double {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if let value = value as? String {
                try container.encode(value)
            } else if value is JSONNull {
                try container.encodeNil()
            } else if let value = value as? [Any] {
                var container = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer()
                try encode(to: &container, array: value)
            } else if let value = value as? [String: Any] {
                var container = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self)
                try encode(to: &container, dictionary: value)
            } else {
                throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
            }
        }
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout KeyedEncodingContainer<JSONCodingKey>, dictionary: [String: Any]) throws {
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            let key = JSONCodingKey(stringValue: key)!
            if let value = value as? Bool {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? Double {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? String {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            } else if value is JSONNull {
                try container.encodeNil(forKey: key)
            } else if let value = value as? [Any] {
                var container = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)
                try encode(to: &container, array: value)
            } else if let value = value as? [String: Any] {
                var container = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self, forKey: key)
                try encode(to: &container, dictionary: value)
            } else {
                throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
            }
        }
    }

    static func encode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer, value: Any) throws {
        if let value = value as? Bool {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? Int64 {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? Double {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if let value = value as? String {
            try container.encode(value)
        } else if value is JSONNull {
            try container.encodeNil()
        } else {
            throw encodingError(forValue: value, codingPath: container.codingPath)
        }
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if var arrayContainer = try? decoder.unkeyedContainer() {
            self.value = try JSONAny.decodeArray(from: &arrayContainer)
        } else if var container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self) {
            self.value = try JSONAny.decodeDictionary(from: &container)
        } else {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            self.value = try JSONAny.decode(from: container)
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        if let arr = self.value as? [Any] {
            var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, array: arr)
        } else if let dict = self.value as? [String: Any] {
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: JSONCodingKey.self)
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, dictionary: dict)
        } else {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try JSONAny.encode(to: &container, value: self.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can decode `JSON` with:

```
let root = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData!)
```

and if you want to access `data` key from your `root` object you can do it with

```
root?.response.data
```

which is An `Array` of type `[Datum]?`

Comment: I can output the datum, by print(root?.response.data). How do I now access the routeKey or routeNAME

Comment: As I told you it's an `Array` let me show you one example for `routeKey` which is `root?.response.data[0].fieldData.routeKey`

Answer (score 1):

The data inside is actually an array. So you can iterate over it and look for the object with desired keys.

```
if let responseData = response["data"] as? [[String : Any]] {
    for aDataItem in responseData {
        print("routeName :\(aDataItem["routeNmae"]) and routeID:\(aDataItem["Route ID"])")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can parse json using multiple ways Codable, Swift Class, Struct and third party frameworks like SwiftyJSON, Gloss, Struct, Unbox, Maya and many other for more detail [CHECK DETAIL LINK](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#json)

Online tool for generating all kinds of models : [jsoncafe.com](http://www.jsoncafe.com/)